# Problems with sorting algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a program which should scan 4 variables N-times (1var - Name, 2var - lastName, 3var - grade, 4 var - score) and print name and last name of man, who have highest score. If we have more than 1 winner, it's prints amount of winners.

I have an algorithm which finds the highest score, but I can't find a solution to the name and the name inscribed on the new variable at a time, when suddenly the next person will be the winner.

How can I do this?

I tried to create a two-dimensional array of rows and exchange in the loop, but nothing happened. All output time only program garbage.

Here's a fragment of my code, I marked problem area with comment:

```
int N, score, grade, amount, k, bestscore;
scanf("%d", &N);
char fname[20], sname[20];
bestscore=0;
 amount=1;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
             {
              scanf("%s %s %d %d", fname, sname, &grade, &score);
              if (score<200)
                      {
                        if (score !=0 && score==bestscore)
                             {
                              amount++;
                             }
                        if (score>bestscore)
                             {
                              //something that solve problem
                             }
                      }
             }
if (amount>1)
   {
   printf("%d", amount);
   }
else printf(%s %s", fname, sname);
```

Comment: Not enough relevant code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: try adding some example data you are working on, the desired result for that data, some code in place of your comment, and the result that produces

Comment: You can just indent the code 4 spaces to make it a code block, or highlight the code and use the "Code Sample" button in the post editor to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which works :

```
./a.out | sed 's/^/    /'
Best Score 2 by John Doe
array[ 0] : (1,Fred,Bloggs)
array[ 1] : (2,John,Doe)
array[ 2] : (0,No,Hoper)
High Score 2 by John Doe
```

The index of highest score is scanned, then it is used to lookup the names in a lookup table.
Generally you want to keep info, so someone with a better personal high score doesnt' have to reenter their name.  It's also much easier to sort the list or save a table in a file; besides making testing easier.

But you can just save the high score record to :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct score {
    int score;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
} score;

score scoretable[] = {
    { 1, "Fred", "Bloggs", },
    { 2, "John", "Doe", },
    { 0, "No", "Hoper", },
};

score high; 


int main( int argc, char **argv) {

    const int N = sizeof scoretable / sizeof (score);
    int bestscore = 0;
    int ibest = -1;

    for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
         if (scoretable[ i].score > bestscore) {
             ibest = i;
         }
    }

    /* Found best score */
    score *sb = &scoretable[ ibest];
    printf( "Best Score %d by %s %s\n", sb->score, sb->fname, sb->lname);

    /* Copy highest score into it's record */
    high = *sb;

    /* Dump all the records in backing store */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("array[ %d] : (%d,%s,%s)\n", i, scoretable[ i].score, scoretable[ i].fname, scoretable[ i].lname);
    }
    printf( "High Score %d by %s %s\n", high.score, high.fname, high.lname);

}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I need. Number of participants and their data is written into the program gradually, we have'nt already pre-defined value. Therefore, the algorithm for obtaining the values is right, not the problem. Everything works as it should, except that I need to bring the desired name and surname. If I could write them into a new variable and overwrite values ​​winners there to the end, when I find out who scored the most points, to output his name and surname. PS Yes, my English is bad, sorry.

Comment: Store them in a table, if you really just want 1 top score record then 1 single structure!  I needed to use a table to test & debug.  You can just add entries as you go along.  If you allocate dynamically, if your table fills then you can allocate a new larger one and copy items over.

Comment: Thanks, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Well I've updated it to save the best score in a record, as you get new scores, you can just test the score against `high.score`, then `strcpy( high.fname, "New name");` if you insist.  I just knocked something up quick to demonstrate, that could be shown to work without wasting time

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your `for(int i=0; ibestscore)` loop is both incomplete and empty. Try adding an increment and case to the For loop, then something to go inside the loop. Perhaps

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  if (playerScore[i] > bestScore)
    bestScore = playerScore[i];
}
```

And keep track of which player had the highest score.

Comment: Hello! Im novice at StackOverFlow and my code was "chewed". I repaired it, now it's updated. Im using C language and cant exchange strings. It's the main problem.